# How to extract the address data from a String in Python

Tags: python, nlp

I am trying to extract relevant address info form an string and discard the garbage.
So this:

```
al domicilio social de la Compañía, Avenida de Burgos, 109 - 28050 Madrid (Indicar Asesoría Jurídica – Protección de Datos)
```

Should be:

```
Avenida de Burgos, 109 - 28050 Madrid
```

What i've done:

I am using stanza NER to find locations from text.

After that, I am using the indexes of the found entities to get the full address.
For eg: If A Madrid (Spanish city) is found in  text[120:128] i will extract the string text[60:101] to get the full address.

My current code is:

```
##
##STANZA NER FOR LOCATIONS
##
!pip install stanza
#Download the spanish model
import stanza
stanza.download('es') 
#create and run the ner tagger
nlp = stanza.Pipeline(lang='es', processors='tokenize,ner')
text = 'al domicilio social de la Compañía, Avenida de Burgos, 109 - 28050 Madrid (Indicar Asesoría Jurídica – Protección de Datos) '
doc = nlp(text)

#print results of NER tagger
print([ent for ent in doc.ents if ent.type=="LOC"], sep='\n')
print(*[text[int(ent.start_char)-60:int(ent.end_char)+15] for ent in doc.ents if ent.type=="LOC"], sep='\n')
```

After this, in this particular case, which should be reproducible. I get the next address.

```
cilio social de la Compañía, Avenida de Burgos, 109 - 28050 Madrid (Indicar Aseso
```

Which contains extra "garbage" info --> " cilio social de la Compañía," and "(Indicar Aseso"

In the next part of the process,I am using the [libpostal](https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal) library to parse the address as it follows:

```
!pip install postal
from postal.parser import parse_address
parse_address('Avenida de Burgos, 109 - 28050 Madrid')
```

Which works reliably in most cases, but only with clean addresses.

```
  [('avenida de burgos', 'road'),
 ('109', 'house_number'),
 ('28050', 'postcode'),
 ('madrid', 'city')]
```

So, to sum up, I am searching from another tecnique apart from regex to help me discard garbage info from addresses apart from regex. (Libraries which do this if they exist or a new NLP approach ... )
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### For US address extraction from bulk text:

For US addresses in bulks of text I have pretty good luck, though not perfect with the below regex. It wont work on many of the oddity type addresses and only captures first 5 of the zip.

Explanation:

- `([0-9]{1,6})` - string of 1-5 digits to start off
- `(.{5,75})` - Any character 5-75 times. I looked at the addresses I was interested in and the vast vast majority were over 5 and under 60 characters for the address line 1, address 2 and city.
- `(BIG LIST OF AMERICAN STATES AND ABBERVIATIONS)` - This is to match on states. Assumes state names will be Title Case.
- `.{1,2}` - designed to accommodate many permutations of ,/s or just /s between the state and the zip
- `([0-9]{5})` - captures first 5 of the zip.

```
text = "is an individual maintaining a residence at 175 Fox Meadow, Orchard Park, NY 14127. 2. other,"

address_regex = r"([0-9]{1,6})(.{5,75}?)((?:Ala(?:(?:bam|sk)a)|American Samoa|Arizona|Arkansas|(?:^(?!Baja )California)|Colorado|Connecticut|Delaware|District of Columbia|Florida|Georgia|Guam|Hawaii|Idaho|Illinois|Indiana|Iowa|Kansas|Kentucky|Louisiana|Maine|Maryland|Massachusetts|Michigan|Minnesota|Miss(?:(?:issipp|our)i)|Montana|Nebraska|Nevada|New (?:Hampshire|Jersey|Mexico|York)|North (?:(?:Carolin|Dakot)a)|Ohio|Oklahoma|Oregon|Pennsylvania|Puerto Rico|Rhode Island|South (?:(?:Carolin|Dakot)a)|Tennessee|Texas|Utah|Vermont|Virgin(?:ia| Island(s?))|Washington|West Virginia|Wisconsin|Wyoming|A[KLRSZ]|C[AOT]|D[CE]|FL|G[AU]|HI|I[ADLN]|K[SY]|LA|M[ADEINOST]|N[CDEHJMVY]|O[HKR]|P[AR]|RI|S[CD]|T[NX]|UT|V[AIT]|W[AIVY])).{1,2}([0-9]{5})"

addresses = re.findall(address_regex, text)
```

addresses is then: `[('175', ' Fox Meadow, Orchard Park, ', 'NY', '', '14127')]`

You can combine these and remove spaces like so:

```
for address in addresses:
    out_address = " ".join(address)
    out_address = " ".join(out_address.split())
```

To then break this into a proper line 1, line 2 etc. I suggest using an address validation API like [Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview) or [Lob](https://www.lob.com/address-verification). These can take a string and break it into parts. There are also some python solutions for this like [usaddress](https://github.com/datamade/usaddress)

#### For outside the US

To port this to other locations suggest considering how this could be adapted to your region. If you have a finite number of states and a similar structure, try looking for someone who has already built the "state" regex for your country.